# Jsp syntax highlighting is not working in netbeans 7.4

Tags: jsp, netbeans

Jsp  syntax highlighting is not working in netbeans 7.4
can any one tell how to enable jsp in netbeans.

Comment: Please elaborate your issue . have you upgraded it recently ?

Comment: my problem solved,anyway thanks for asking. I installed java SE version of netbeans. It will not support jsp. So, i installed Java EE version which supports jsp.